# Exception deserializing the package error when executing SSIS package

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I've just installed Visual studio Professional 2015 on a Microsoft 2019 Server with the following tools:

- VS update 3
- Sql Server Data Tools
- BI Developer Extensions for Visual Studio 2015
- Apex tools
- ZappySys SSIS tools

When I go to run an SSIS package that works on other machines I get the following error message:

```
TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
------------------------------

Exception deserializing the package "The type initializer for 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.XMLSerializationHelper' threw an exception.".

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The type initializer for 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.XMLSerializationHelper' threw an exception. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS)

------------------------------

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace, Version=14.100.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS)

------------------------------

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've repaired SQL Server Data tools and Visual studio itself with no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the protection level on the package? If you have custom components in this package, take them out one by one and see if it works.

Comment: So the protection level is 'EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey'. I've created a new solution and reloaded a project that I know has no custom components and works on our sql server and development machines. I'm still getting the same error. I've gone as far as creating a new solution with a new Integrated service project in it. I do a simple SQL statement 'select 1' and still get the error.

Comment: Here's one similiar error https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8f2a29a4-0014-4ba2-921e-e38136d5acba/failed-to-start-project-microsoft-visual-studio?forum=ssdt

Comment: and another .... https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c6054dbb-8b59-4635-a4aa-ef3d0acef505/microsoft-visual-studio?forum=ssdt

Answer (score 3):

I had created a new `SSIS project` and facing same problem while executing it.
Generally this type of issue occurred when you have not selected the right `SQL Server Version`.
You have to first check the `SQL Server version` installed in your or remote machine and verify it with the `SSIS Project`. You have choose the same SQL Server version in `Visual studio` for your `SSIS project`.

> `SSIS Project>>Right Click (properties)>>Configuration Properties>>General>>Target Server Version`

After setting this if still you are facing the same issue then please check the below settings.

> `SSIS Project>>Right Click (properties)>>Common Properties>>project>>Security>>Select the appropriate protection level.`

**`Solution-1`**
[image]

[image]

**`Solution-2`**

[image]

Comment: Works for me, thanks